# How to verify facebook messenger installed on devices?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

Our team has built Facebook messenger for subscribers. We are releasing a beta version and we want to pick up 5% for getting feedback. The challenge is how can we verify which subs have Facebook Messenger installed on their devices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have phone numbers for the subscribers you can use the Customer Matching API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/customer-matching

If you don't, you can try to get them to interact with your bot with a Send To Messenger button or one of the other web plugins. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger

Comment: Hey amuramoto. Many thanks for your answer! It is helpful, I will leave the question open for one or days for getting more help!  If your answer is the best, I would check it as the answer, thanks again